# Error: ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater (need track by $index)

Tags: angularjs

https://plnkr.co/edit/bpFi5WuojpNO2rh5vF3T?p=preview

See the README in the Plunker for the following explaination:

I would like the "INJECT NEW" button to create a blank input under
the one that was clicked, not at the end.

The reason they are getting added at the end is because of :

```
<div ng-repeat="problem in problems track by $index">
```

The `track by $index` is breaking the injection.

If I take out the `track by $index` then I get the error:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=problem%20in%20problems&p1=object:171&p2={%22key%22:null,%22component%22:null,%22$$hashKey%22:%22object:171%22}

How can I have the inject functionality but not get the error?

Comment: if you will not add track by $index then you will get the error for duplicate

Comment: Correct. I want to remove the track by, but allow for it to still "inject"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can change the method like below and can get it working :

```
$scope.addMotFault = function(idx) {
    if ($scope.problems.length > 1) {

        // Now more than one item, we need to 
        // inject the additional one under the clicked item

        // this index + 1
        problemPrototype.key = idx + 1;
        $scope.problems.splice(idx + 1, 0, angular.copy(problemPrototype));


    } else {

        // Only one item, so just push new problem
        // no need to "inject"

        problemPrototype.key = 0;
        $scope.problems.push(angular.copy(problemPrototype));
    }

};
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="problem in problems" style="border: 1px #ccc solid; margin:5px; padding: 5px">
```

It would work i believe.

Comment: Yes, that should work. Please have a look at this updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/V0YnYvfkIN19GBjWuKgN?p=preview).

Comment: PERFECT. I had an idea that I may have to use angular.copy but didn't know how. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I am sending you the required answer.

Please find the attached link and go through the code. you will find the solution.

https://plnkr.co/edit/nhqAnD1hSKuIs9HTsT30?p=preview
you can use ng-if in place $first and can check on the basis on length.
`<button ng-click="removeMotFault($index)" ng-if="problems.length > 1">REMOVE</button>`